# Artifactory upgrade failure helm chart 7.18.3 to 8.4.7

Tags: upgrade, artifactory, kubernetes-helm

We're running an older version of artifactory in a kubernetes cluster  that uses the postgresql database chart included with artifactory.  The chart 7.18.3 was used to standup the artifactory instance.  With the latest vulnerabilities report, we decided to upgrade our artifactory to the latest version.  It was recommended to step up through the various revisions to make sure that the postgresql gets the necessary changes to go to the latest version.  So I decided to upgrade to the 8.4.7 chart before upgrading to the 9.2.9 chart.  I've read the README included with the charts and made sure that my database was ready for the upgrade.  I didn't pass in a password for the database when I initially setup the artifactory instance so I pulled the existing password before upgrading. I then perform the upgrade as directed by the readme with the flags --set databaseUpgradeReady=yes and --set postgresql.postgresqlPassword=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}.  I'm getting a 404 error after the upgrade:

```
Message /artifactory/webapp/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

One thing that I noticed is that prior to the upgrade there is only one artifactory-postgresql service and after the upgrade I have two postgresql services: artifactory-postgresql and artifactory-postgresql-headless.Digging into it, the headless service is created when a clusterIP is not passed in, but I haven't seen a way to pass the clusterIP to the artifactory-postgresql chart included in artifactory.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory Upgrade using postgresql from 7.x to 9.x chart versions is a two step process

1. First upgrade 7.x to 8.x (Manual process involves export/import of data)
2. Then upgrade 8.x to 9.x chart versions

Please refer below for detailed steps :
https://github.com/jfrog/charts/blob/master/stable/artifactory/UPGRADE_NOTES.md

Note: For faster responses for your issues , Feel free to raise issues directly [here](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/issues)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Those were the instructions I was working off of.  I am still getting the 404 error when the bringing artifactory up after the chart upgrade to 8.X.  I don't have the opportunity to load the existing data.  I will look at the link you have posted for additional help.